# what is the reason of this of the following statement?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

in a paper i saw the following statement:

Let $\Phi:B(X)\longrightarrow B(X)$ is an additive and surjective map. If $T\in B(X)$ and for some $x\in X$

$Tx \otimes {\Phi(T)}^*f=\Phi(T)x\otimes T^*f$  ,implies that 
$\Phi(T)x$ and $Tx$ are linearly dependent. 
what is the reason?

($x\otimes f $ means  a rank one operator )

thank you for your help.

Comment: What is $\Phi$?  Is $\Phi \in B(X)$, or is $\Phi \in B(B(X))$?

Comment: Also, presumably $X$ is a Banach space.  It's not also a Hilbert space by any chance, is it?

Comment: @joker: 
you could also accept these answers : [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786462), [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530358),  [(3)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496820),  [(4)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959184),  [(5)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959459),  [(6)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049801),  [(7)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962174),  [(8)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040349). Many thanks :-) !

Comment: And maybe these ones:   [(9)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037878),  [(10)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960976),  [(11)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780970),  [(12)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808840), [(13)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780533), [(14)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776813), [(15)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776756), [(16)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667228), [(17)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597983).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
Tx \otimes \Phi(T)^*f = \Phi(T)x \otimes T^*f \implies\\
\langle (Tx \otimes \Phi(T)^*f)(y),g \rangle = 
\langle (\Phi(T)x \otimes T^*f)(y),g \rangle \quad \forall y \in X, g \in X^* \implies\\
g([\Phi(T)^*f(y)]Tx) =
g([T^*f(y)]\Phi(T)x) \quad \forall y \in X, g \in X^* \implies\\
g([f(\Phi(T)y)]Tx) =
g([f(Ty)]\Phi(T)x) \quad \forall y \in X, g \in X^* \implies\\
[f(\Phi(T)y)]g(Tx) =
[f(Ty)]g(\Phi(T)x) \quad \forall y \in X, g \in X^*
$$
Now, if we fix a $y$ such that either $\Phi(T)y$ or $Ty$ are not in $\ker f$, we see that there are constants $\alpha, \beta$ (not both zero) such that
$$
\alpha \,g(Tx) = \beta \,g(\Phi(T)x) \quad \forall g \in X^*
$$
which is to say that $Tx$ and $\Phi(T)x$ are linearly dependent.